# Is it possible to obtain the ServicePath when querying entities in Orion?

Tags: fiware-orion

the question I'd like to ask was raised some time ago ([FIWARE Orion: How to retrieve the servicePath of an entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217659/fiware-orion-how-to-retrieve-the-servicepath-of-an-entity)) but as far as I've seen, there is no final answer.

In short, I'd like to retrieve the service path of entities when I exec a GET query to */v2/entitites* which returns multiple results.

In our FIWARE instance, we strongly rely on the servicePath element to differentiate between entities with the same id. It is not a good design choice but, unfortunately, we cannot change it as many applications use that id convention at the moment.

There was an attempt three years ago to add a virtual field 'servicePath' to the query result (https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/pull/2880) but the pull request was discarded because it didn't include test coverage for that feature and the final NGSIv2 spec didn't include that field.

**Is there any plan to implement such feature in the future?** I guess the answer is no, what brings me to the next question: **is there any other way to do it which does not involve creating subscriptions** (we found that the initial notification of a subscription does give you that info, but the notification is limited to 1000 results, what is too low for the number of entities we want to retrieve, and it does not allow pagination either)?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to use an attribute (provided by the context producer application) to keep the service path. Somehow, this is the same idea of the builtin attribute proposed in [PR #2880](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/pull/2880).